# Named control exists on Windows 10 but not on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1-universal

I have the following code in a Windows 8.1 Store App. This code runs perfectly fine on Windows 10 but crashes on Windows 8.1. The second named control in MainPage.xaml.cs is null on Win 8.1 but not on Windows 10. It's not a timing issue as the named control still won't be populated in any subsequent event handler following the page load. What on earth is going on here?

To summarize, I have a ContentControl with a ContentPresenter defined in its Template. That ContentControl is then instantiated on a page, with a named child control (using "x:Name") as its Content. On Windows 10, that named control exists in code-behind. On Windows 8.1 it is null

**MyUserControl1.xaml**

```
<ContentControl
x:Class="App1.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<ContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentControl.Template>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock1" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               TextAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="50" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />

    <local:MyUserControl1 Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock2" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="50" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </local:MyUserControl1>

</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            TextBlock1.Text = "This works";
            TextBlock2.Text = "This does not work because TextBlock2 is null";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you call MyUserControl1.ApplyTemplate() before attempting to access TextBlock2?

Comment: Nah. It didn't help. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot reference this. Your `TextBlock2` is explicitly being set BY YOU to be the content of *another* control fundamentally out of scope.  After rendering is complete, your `TextBlock2` is no longer a child of your `MainPage` but instead a child of the `ControlTemplate` in your `UserControl`. Windows 10 is behaving EXACTLY how it should, and it appears you have discovered a bug in the Windows 8 rendering engine, if it worked.

### One

There are a few workarounds. The first is the textbook approach of adding a property to your `UserControl` that adds access to this control. Because you are allowing the content to be dynamic, the operation inside that property (or method) would also need to be dynamic. Something like `GetControl<TextBlock>("TextBlock1")` which could hunt for you.

```
public bool TryGetControl<T>(string name, out T control)
{
    try
    {
        var children = RecurseChildren(this.MyUserControl);
        control = children
            .Where(x => Equals(x.Name, name))
            .OfType<T>()
            .First();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        control = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}

public List<Control> RecurseChildren(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var list = new List<Control>();
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    var children = Enumerable.Range(0, count - 1)
        .Select(x => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, x));
    list.AddRange(children.OfType<Control>());
    foreach (var child in children)
    {
        list.AddRange(RecurseChildren(child));
    }
    return list;
}
```

### Two

The second thing you could do is simply hunt for the control through the child hierarchy of the `UserControl` from the page itself. The logic would be the same as number one (above) but it would execute inside the page and not be part of your `UserControl` logic. You already do this sort of thing when you need to find the `ScrollViewer` in a `ListView` or maybe the inner `Border` in a `Button` for some reason.

> It turns out I have already explained this in a blog article you can use as reference: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

### Three

And here's a third, perhaps simplest way to do it. Handle the `Loaded` event of `TextBlock1` in your `MainPage` and set a field to the value of the `sender` in the handler method. You can even cast it to `TextBlock` so everything is typed. This gives you simple access, but has the potential downside of timing. If you try to access the field value before it is set, you might find it is null. But, in most cases, this works the easiest.

So, that's three ways to handle it. I think it is very important that you recognize that this is EXPECTED behavior since a XAML element can have only one parent and you are setting that parent through the `Content` property of your `ContentPresenter`. That being said, it might be expected behavior, but it is not obviously intuitive.

Best of luck.

Comment: Re: "Windows 10 is behaving EXACTLY how it should, and it appears you have discovered a bug in the Windows 8 rendering engine, if it worked"  

I think you misunderstand. Windows 10 is the one that doesn't crash. Everything works fine on Windows 10. Windows 8.1 is the one that does crash. Are you saying that because Windows 10 *doesn't* crash, that it's the one that has the bug?  

This behavior is very dangerous because I do all my development on Windows 10. I get done with a control, everything works fine on my machine, I turn it over to QA, and everything explodes!

Comment: Also, if this is EXPECTED behavior, what should I do differently to get the effect I want?

Comment: Dude, I have you three things to do to get what you want. Your question said you wanted to reference an element that is out of scope. That's what I gave you, even the sample code to do it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Jerry, I was already aware that by traversing the control tree I could find those controls. I am looking for something I can do to restructure my XAML so that the code behind still works. I have hundreds of controls being referenced by name in the code behind of my actual project and I cannot replace them all.

Comment: I no longer believe my answer is correct when I say Windows 8 is right and Windows 10 is wrong. I am sorry to be unclear. It appears, as I am creating controls myself, that this behavior in Windows 10 is not only appropriate, but superior in many ways. I hate it when I am wrong, but I think it is important I tell you what I am learning. I will need to reach out to the platform team and see if I can ask them explicitly for a answer. I will point out that my "traverse the tree" solution is certainly valid. It's the default behavior, which is right, I am questioning. Again, sorry.